# Using a bicycle to calculate areas

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm organizing a maths divulgation thing on my school and I found this interesting talk on youtube where a mathematician uses a bicycle to calculate the area inside a closed curve. Here it is: https://youtu.be/hukIyIYjto4?t=2827 (it starts at 47:07, and, well ,it's in Portuguese) He walks the front wheel of the bicycle through the curve, and uses the distance traveled by the back wheel to calculate the area.

We would like to replicate this experiment, but the video doesn't give enough details to do that, nor does it give any information on the mathematics behind it... can somebody here help us out on finding out more information on this thing?

Comment: Look up a planimeter, a smaller model. Basically, it all boils down to Green's Theorem.